# Opengraph actions submission

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, submission

I try to submit my action for approval on the facebook platform,

But they ask me to change something:

> In the developer submission tool, please change your action conjugations to: commented on, commented on, is commenting on, are commenting on

I submited the action a second time and asked more informations... the answer was the same, and nobody seems to be able to help on the facebook side.

If i understand, they ask me to modify the comment conjugations with the "on" but this is already the case and i do not know how to fix that.

I am tired to try to implement this action on facebook since facebook can't answer with a more explicit message...

Any help on the subject ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the 'Sentence Previews' section below the part of the interface in your screenshot and it should be more clear why they're asking you to change it

With what you have there, the stories on Facebook will be of the format

`Ahwebdev commented an article on **`

or

`Ahwebdev commented <ARTICLE TITLE HERE> on **`

The 'on' in the first line of your screenshot is immediately before the app name, not just before the object type name / object title

Comment: I just went to the submission interface, the action is now approved without any changes. In my last submission, i asked facebook to explain me what to do with more details. it was the first day at work for the moderator :)